# How to get a user and all of its images in one request?

Tags: sql

I have a user with a has_many images join table.

I know I can do a:

```
select *
from user,
     image
join user_images on...
where user_id = 'some_id'
```

This will give me the data in one request however each image row will have all of the user data in it duplicated.

```
user_name, address, phone, image_1, image_1_path
user_name, address, phone, image_2, image_2_path
....
```

Is there a way to do this in one query without any data duplication?

I guess an ideal data response would be something like:

I guess what would be ideal is a response like:

```
user_name, address, phone
image_1, image_1_path
image_2, image_2_path
...<more unique images>
```

Comment: you can use distinct

Comment: Thanks for response. I should have clarified all the rows would be distinct. i.e. Each user would have one set of unique images. 
The response would be a set of distinct rows but still have that durn data replication.

Comment: can you share your sample data and what you want as a output from that

Comment: Sorry. Forgot comment won't let code formatting so updated orig question.

Comment: Don't mix old implicit joins with modern explicit joins... Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have such a response? It seems that you're mixing up user_name and image_1 into same column, address and image_1_path into same column. It might save some bytes, but really looks like maintenance nightmare.

Comment: It would be for a super high volume site, so I was just thinking it might help? Maybe not though? Not sure if the bytes saving would help out with bandwidth issues over thousands of QPS.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be brought back in a single request?

Comment: No more than a thousand probably. Does it seem worth it?

Comment: Depending on what kind of SQL flavor you use, you could put user images data into a JSON/XML formatted string and then just serialize it in your application. I personally would have two separate calls to the database.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to see the blank `user_name`, `address` and `phone` if there are multiple images per the same user. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in the following:

```
select 
    case when rn > 1 then '' else user_name end as user_name, 
    case when rn > 1 then '' else address end as address, 
    case when rn > 1 then '' else phone end as phone,
    image,
    image_path 
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by user_name, address, phone order by user_name) rn 
    from user
    join user_images on...
    where user_id = 'some_id'
) x
```

Comment: Wow. That's impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Look at me! Look at me! :)

So, next I explain it in my understanding:

Now I have two tables: `user`、`image`

Ⅰ`user` data structure and hypothetical data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzXn.png)

Ⅱ`image` data structure and hypothetical data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mDnP.png)

Ⅲ OK, let's select some data in similar to your SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `user`
LEFT JOIN image 
ON `user`.id = image.user_id
```

AND, the result show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl6mh.png)

BUT, this is no what we want!

Ⅳ Final SQL:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.`name`,
    b.img
FROM
    `user` a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(image) AS img
    FROM
        image
    GROUP BY
        user_id
) b ON a.id = b.user_id
```

above SQL executing result show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGO4s.png)

Ⅴ real final message :))

Is this what you want?